# Are there common errors concering split app in UI5 Stack 1.34?

Tags: master-detail, sapui5

I'm facing a curios error while working with a split app on stack 1.34.

On initial load the first entry should be displayed in the detail section. Unfortunately, this does not work. Instead, if I click on the second entry, the first entry will be displayed. If I click on the first entry again, the second entry will be displayed. And so on.

I could not reproduce this error on a other system with 1.28. There, everything works fine on the same code-basis.

So maybe it's a bug of 1.34? Any other ideas?

Update:
This is a snippet from my index.html. Maybe it's because of the AppCacheBuster?

```
<script src="resources/sap-ui-cachebuster/sap-ui-core.js"
        id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
        data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.commons, sap.m"
        data-sap-ui-appCacheBuster="./, ../ui5_common"
        data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
           data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{  
              "my.project" : "./",
              "my.base" : "../ui5_common/"
            }'
        data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"> 
</script>
```

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example in a Plunker to reproduce this? Are the ids of your entries the same by accident?

Comment: Sorry. You can find the coding [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36179369/detail-page-of-split-app-without-model/36181516#36181516)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not what exactly causes this error, but in the meanwhile it is working well. I guess the error was based on a bunch of minor errors and misconfigurations.